# Getting A Child Node In Java From XML

Tags: java, xml, parsing, nodes

Here is my XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <Pport xmlns="http://www.thalesgroup.com/rtti/PushPort/v12" xmlns:ns3="http://www.thalesgroup.com/rtti/PushPort/Forecasts/v2" ts="2016-07-26T20:51:30.9941484+01:00" version="12.0">
  <uR updateOrigin="TD">
   <TS rid="201607264120116" ssd="2016-07-26" uid="W44875">
    <ns3:Location tpl="LEEE" wtp="21:00:30">
     <ns3:pass et="20:57" src="TD"/>
     <ns3:plat cisPlatsup="true" platsrc="A" platsup="true">1</ns3:plat>
    </ns3:Location>
    <ns3:Location tpl="LEESPRJ" wtp="21:02:30">
     <ns3:pass et="20:59" src="Darwin"/>
    </ns3:Location>
    <ns3:Location tpl="GRVPDCE" wtp="21:15:30">
     <ns3:pass et="21:12" src="Darwin"/>
    </ns3:Location>
    <ns3:Location tpl="GRVPCSD" wta="21:21">
     <ns3:arr et="21:17" src="Darwin"/>
    </ns3:Location>
   </TS>
  </uR>
 </Pport>
```

Here is my JAVA code (part of)

```
 try {
                    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                    factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
                    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
                    InputSource is = new InputSource(new StringReader(xml));
                    Document doc = builder.parse(is);

                    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
                    System.out.println("Root Element : " + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());

                    NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagNameNS(
                            "http://www.thalesgroup.com/rtti/PushPort/Forecasts/v2", "Location");
                    int totalBooks = nList.getLength();
                    System.out.println(totalBooks);

                    NodeList arrList = doc
                            .getElementsByTagNameNS("http://www.thalesgroup.com/rtti/PushPort/Forecasts/v2", "arr");
                    int totalArrives = arrList.getLength();
                    System.out.println(totalArrives);


                    for (int i = 0; i < nList.getLength(); i++) {
                        Node nNode = nList.item(i);
                        if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                            Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
                            System.out.println(eElement.getAttribute("tpl"));

                            String tpl = eElement.getAttribute("tpl");
                            String pta = eElement.getAttribute("pta");
                            String ptd = eElement.getAttribute("ptd");
                            String wta = eElement.getAttribute("wta");
                            String wtd = eElement.getAttribute("wtd");

                            String query = "insert into darwinall (tpl,timestamp,pta,ptd,wta,wtd)"
                                    + "values(?,?,?,?,?,?)";
                            try {
                                PreparedStatement preparedStmt = connectOut.connect().prepareStatement(query);
                                preparedStmt.setString(1, tpl);
                                preparedStmt.setInt(2, 123456);
                                preparedStmt.setString(3, pta);
                                preparedStmt.setString(4, ptd);
                                preparedStmt.setString(5, wta);
                                preparedStmt.setString(6, wtd);

                                preparedStmt.execute();
                            } catch (SQLException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }

                        // New Code
                        NodeList children = nList.item(i).getChildNodes();
                        for (int j = 0; j < children.getLength(); j++) {
                            Node cNode = nList.item(i);
                            if (cNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                                Element eElement = (Element) cNode;
                                System.out.println(eElement.getAttribute("et"));
                            }
                        }


                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
```

I can successfully get the values attributed to the NS3:Location node but cannot get the child node values of 'et' under NS3:arr......that part of my code is where I say //New Code. I am new to JAVA . Can anybody help me get the value of 'et' under NS3:arr ...ie the answer is 21.17. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

be carrefull you try to get data from nlist you must use children object.
then replace

```
Node cNode = nList.item(i);
```

by

```
Node cNode = children.item(j);
```

as below:

```
     NodeList children = nList.item(i).getChildNodes();
         for (int j = 0; j < children.getLength(); j++) {

             Node cNode = children.item(j);
             if (cNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                 Element eElement = (Element) cNode;
                 System.out.println(eElement.getAttribute("et"));
             }
         }
```